# insert a sign (eg., +) between elements of vector

Tags: r, text, character

I would like to insert a plus sign between each names

```
    > data(iris)
    > colnames(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

Ideally to obtain

```
Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species
```

But when I search this, most people are trying to get rid of + sign from r instead of inserting it. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `paste0(colnames(iris), collapse=" + ")`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Or `paste(names(iris), collapse=" + ")`, 4 characters shorter :-)

Comment: colnames(Iris).join("+")

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr and @PoGibas! Both work well. Do you know to remove the quotation marks before and after the the result?

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendieck! I am actually running "coxph(Surv(formula) ~., iris) I tried the ~. function but got odd error messages. I will research a little how to troubleshoot.

Comment: @PoGibas: I haven't tested it but I'm fairly certain `paste0` is faster (not that it matters in this use case). @G.Grothendieck: ++nice intuit about the ultimate use-case.

Comment: I have transferred my comments to an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments under the question the poster's application is to coxph regression in which case this works.  We will use the `rats` dataset as our example.  Both it and coxph are in the survival package.

```
library(survival)

fm <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~., rats)
fm
```

giving:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ., data = rats)

           coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z       p
litter  0.00847   1.00850  0.00534  1.58  0.1131
rx      0.80530   2.23736  0.30943  2.60  0.0093
sexm   -3.08512   0.04572  0.72493 -4.26 2.1e-05

Likelihood ratio test=52.6  on 3 df, p=2.25e-11
n= 300, number of events= 42
```

Although we don't really need the following note that we can get the expanded formula as a by-product of running coxph like this:

```
formula(fm)
## Surv(time, status) ~ litter + rx + sex
```

Alternately, see the comments under the question for ways to get the right hand side of the formula as a string using string manipulation.

Comment: thanks for making this as an answer but it does not answer my question that I initiated. I don't want to include everything using the "." I have more than 2000 targets and would like to include maybe 1800, cannot find a good way out yet..

Comment: If you want to only use some of columns in your dataset then just use `coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ., rats[j])` where `j` is an index vector picking out which columns to include in the model.  If you only want to use a subset of rows then use the `subset` argument of `coxph`.